# how to set proper environment diplay settings for 3840x2160 resoultion on Asus Zenbook Pro UX501

Tags: laptop, keyboard-layout, asus, fingerprint-reader, 4k-monitor

how to set proper environment diplay settings for 3840x2160 resoultion on Asus Zenbook Pro UX501. fonts are miniaturized. keyboard not localized. Why Ubuntu is not able to recognize the hardware and install proper drivers?

Answer (score 0):

The font size issue is easy to fix, and I doubt that it has anything to do with the drivers. Open Settings and go to Displays. There, select 200% under Scale. Now apply the changes when prompted and your screen should go back to normal size.
As for the keyboard, is the correct information shown in the Region & Language section of Settings? If not, change those to reflect your hardware. (You should have been able to select them when installing as well.)
I hope this helps!